# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'source-map' when running angular on raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, angular, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on a Angular application which I plan on running on a Raspberry Pi. But, when trying to start the application, the following error occurs:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'source-map'
Require stack:
- /home/pi/Desktop/SESAME/SESAME/src/tailwind/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/utils/template.js
- /home/pi/Desktop/SESAME/SESAME/src/tailwind/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/utils/index.js
- /home/pi/Desktop/SESAME/SESAME/src/tailwind/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/experimental/jobs/create-job-handler.js
- /home/pi/Desktop/SESAME/SESAME/src/tailwind/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/experimental/jobs/index.js
- /home/pi/Desktop/SESAME/SESAME/src/tailwind/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/experimental.js
- /home/pi/Desktop/SESAME/SESAME/src/tailwind/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/index.js
- /home/pi/Desktop/SESAME/SESAME/src/tailwind/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect.js
- /home/pi/Desktop/SESAME/SESAME/src/tailwind/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/index.js
- /home/pi/Desktop/SESAME/SESAME/src/tailwind/node_modules/@angular-builders/custom-webpack/dist/dev-server/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve-impl.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
See "/tmp/ng-SQBaqf/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I have tried:

- To uninstall and re-install angular cli
- To install all dependencies
  with `npm install`
- To run `npm install @types/source-map@0.5.2`, as suggested [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/23649)

How does one resolve it?

Comment: Will you please upload package.json file. It will give more clarity.

Comment: Sure thing, here it is : https://pastebin.com/UpM2DPEp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you already tried deleting the node_modules directory and running npm install afterwards?

Comment: If this does not help you, you might wanna go into your tsconfig.json and set the "moduleResolution" to "node".

Comment: Thank you, it is now compiling. However, it does not display anything.